# MySQL with php, displaying 50 most recent

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have a database which simply records words in a table in a single column (with RID beside). All I want to do is display the words in order with a space in between (which I have a working code for below)

```
<?php
 $mysql_host = "mysql1.000webhost.com";
 $mysql_database = "db name";
 $mysql_user = "user";
 $mysql_password = "pass";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli(     "mysql1.000webhost.com","databaseuser","password","databasename");
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }

 $sql = 'SELECT Words FROM Poetry '; 
 $result = $conn->query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 echo $row["Words"]. " ";
 }
 } else {
 echo "0 results";
 }
 ?>
```

HOWEVER. I want to only display a set amount (say 50) of the MOST RECENT db entries (i.e) the 50 with the highest RID. Can somebody quickly tell me what code I need (in php) which will display the 50 most recent on a web page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it with PHP, just add it to your query.

```
 $sql = 'SELECT Words FROM Poetry order by RID desc limit 50';
```

This query will order the result set by RID descending, most recent first I'm assuming, and limit the result set to 50 records.

Answer (score 1):

## You can use

```
SELECT Words FROM Poetry order by RID desc limit 0,50
```

0 is the offset and 50 is limit.u can dynamically change those value  if needed.

For the better security purpose You can use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) prepared statements.
  You can see [dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli) for Dynamically Bind Params

Answer (score 0):

Try saving it in a variable and echoing it after your while statement.

Something like this

```
$all_words = '';

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$all_words = "$all_words, $row['Words']";
}
echo"$all_words";

} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```